# Border radius issue with div

Tags: css

I have a CSS flexbox with a div set on the HTML canvas.
I want to have a border-radius around all four corners. I have tried using `border-radius: 80px;` but in vain.
[A quick fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/opankajkumar/zxajhmpo/1/).
I want something like this. Chiseled at all the corners. [image]
But I am getting this.[image]
 Please help.

Comment: It's not clear what you want but have you tried adding a border, ie `border: 1px solid black;`? If I've missed the mark, it would be good if you could show the kind of result you want

Comment: My bad. I want border-radius on all the four corners

Comment: You appear to already have that so again, what kind of result do you want? You might need to get out MSPaint and post some picture examples

Comment: Do you want to set individual border-radius each corner?

Comment: Add example to clarify your question.

Comment: Ideally I would like to have one radius value for all corners. I don't know why it has been limited to top left corner only.

Comment: I have added images to show what I want. Guys, I am not able to set border-radius for all four corners using `border-radius:80px`. That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is `overflow: scroll;`. Remove `overflow: ?;` property from `.stage-area`. With `border-radius` `overflow: scroll;` will not work together it should be `hidden` or `inherit`. Below the snippet.

```
.stage-area {
  width: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 24px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 80px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 80px;
  -moz-border-radius: 80px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 60%;
  /*overflow: scroll;*/
}
```

[image]

```css
.stage-area {
  width: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 24px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 80px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 80px;
  -moz-border-radius: 80px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 60%;
  /*overflow: scroll;*/
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #ffce31;
}

.brand-icon {
  padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
}

.outer-yellow-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div className="outer-yellow-area">
        <img className="brand-icon" src={brandIcon} alt="logo" />
        <div class="stage-area">
        Center stage
        <div>below stage</div>
        <div>below stage</div>
        <div>below stage</div>
        <div>below stage</div>
        <div>below stage</div>
        <div>below stage</div>
        <div>below stage</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Got it now. I knew I was messing somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I have checked you fiddle, its working as you want, the only problem is you have added overflow: scroll; which is causing this problem you are facing.

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hco3a4f5/)

```
overflow:scroll;
```

remove this.

If ned something else, feel free to share

Comment: Maybe if I want overflow as well then it should be inside another div.

Comment: Yes..But no... If you need overflow then add some padding or best solution is to have overflow auto not scroll. So if your content is more than the div size only then you will see scroll otherwise not

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like this: border-radius with overflow: scroll,then this is the answer.Else, please let me know.

[image]

```
<div className="outer-yellow-area">
    <img className="brand-icon" src={brandIcon} alt="logo" />
    <div class="stage-area">
    Center stage
    <div class="bstage">
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>
    <div>below stage</div>

            </div>


    </div>
  </div>
```

and CSS

```
  .stage-area {
    width: 50%;
    height: 60%;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 24px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    border:10px solid transparent;



    }

 .bstage{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    max-height: 100px;
    }

 .bstage::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: .8em;

    }

 .bstage::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-radius: 30px;



    }

 .bstage::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius:30px;
    height: 5px;


    }

  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #ffce31;
    }

 .brand-icon {
    padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
    }

 .outer-yellow-area {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a14ythfg/

Comment: Well, this looks beautiful. I had applied similar scroll effects to my page. But as per the question, the trouble was with `border-radius` and it's solved

Comment: Thank You.The scroll bar was also not working inside the box.So, I have solved that too.